# Adding key to multiple values in an object

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to grab a string value from a text box and multiple values from a multiselect list and associate them where the string value is the key, and the multiple values from the drop down list are the values.

Here is the javascript code I have thus far:

```
var serviceName = document.getElementById('servicePackageText').value;
var sourceType = document.getElementById("multiple-checkboxes");

var groupName = serviceGroupName;
var serviceArray = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < sourceType.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
  serviceArray.push(parseInt(sourceType.selectedOptions[i].value));
}
```

I want the format to look like this:

```
"Textbox value": [  
  multiselect_values,
  multiselect_values,
  multiselect_values,
  multiselect_values
]
```

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] along with actual expected results. Click on `<>` in question editor to make it runnable within this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wrapper object, then it is easy. All you have to do is use `[]` property accessor to assign the object property.

I took some liberty with your code to make it simpler to rationalize:

```js
var serviceName = "myDog"; //mock document.getElementById('servicePackageText').value;
var sourceType = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //mock document.getElementById("multiple-checkboxes");

var groupName = {};
groupName[serviceName] = sourceType; // <--- THE ANSWER

console.log(groupName);
```